Raster Calculator tool change in QGIS
I installed the PCRAster toolbox in QGIS but afterwards the Raster calculator tool in raster analysis is not working as it should. the icon changed likei am showing below:

and when I open the tool it looks like this:
Does anyone have any idea why this happens and if I could fix it, or if there is any other alternative to that?

How do you expect it to look? Are you perhaps thinking of the raster calculator that is accessed by Raster > Raster Calculator ?

Hi Matt, Thanks a lot. Thats wha I needed! Cheers
